# dialog insided onReceive is throwing Exception : unable to add window -- token null is not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-dialog

I have broadcastReceiver that activates upon boot completed. The reason is  I want to reschedule all alarms after a device restart. However, I want to show a dialog that asks the user if they want to proceed. This is the code

```
public class StartupAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context con;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            con = context;
            AlertDialog.Builder actionBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            actionBuilder.setTitle("test");
            actionBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to restart alarms?"); 
            actionBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            actionBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = actionBuilder.create();

            alert.show();

        }
}       

}
```

However I am getting the exception:

```
11-25 18:51:31.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1949): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-25 18:51:31.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:693)
11-25 18:51:31.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:313)
11-25 18:51:31.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
```

I think I know the reason why but I dont know how to fix it. I think (from reading in SO) the reason is that dialog takes an activity so it can be shown and since I am not within my app, I dont have activity. So is there a way  I can show dialog after restart? I can show a Toast but it fails with dialog

unless my theory is wrong and I am missing a whole point. Please help , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to start a new activity with transparent background. I know the solution which is clean without starting activity.
Add this additional line of code

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and also add the following permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

That's it, now the AlertDialog will work in BroadcastReceiver without any error. Visit [this link](http://myonlinestay.com/how-to-create-android-alertdialog-in-broadcastreceiver-or-service/) for full tutorial if you don't understand...

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question better

Answer (score 2):

You have to start an activity (with transparent background) and then put your dialog on the onCreate function. Than close your activity when dialog is closed.

Comment: Is there is no any other solution ? but thanks for this transparent thing.

Comment: as I know no there no other solution... You can also start an activity with dialog theme. But you have to start an activity.

Answer (score 0):

your theory is good, you can only create an AlertDialog though an Activity.
I think you should call an activity from your broadcast receiver (startActivity), then this activity would show this dialog.